How would I get an element value by class?
I want to get the values of "data id" using the class below and put them into an array.
<div data-id="111" class="tr svelte-1q11k9a" style="z-index: auto;">
<div data-id="222" class="tr svelte-1q11k9a" style="z-index: auto;">
<div data-id="333" class="tr svelte-1q11k9a" style="z-index: auto;">

I have tried this but it returned "undefined".
const ex = await page.$$eval("div[class='tr svelte-1q11k9a']", ({ data-id }) => data-id);
    console.log(ex)


I'd try const ids = await page.$$eval("div.tr.svelte-1q11k9a", divs => divs.map(div => div.getAttribute('data-id')));

This question is similar to: how to get value by class name using javascript. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Read How do I get the value of text input field using JavaScript?

The issue lies in how you're trying to extract the data-id attribute. The syntax for destructuring { data-id } is invalid because property names with hyphens cannot be directly destructured in JavaScript objects as it is used a minus operator.
Try the below code, but I would prefer if you could name the attribute as data_id.
const ex = await page.$$eval("div.tr.svelte-1q11k9a", (elements) => {
    return elements.map(el => el.getAttribute("data-id"));
});
console.log(ex);

